# Is the header X-Cloud-Trace-Context set for GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to figure out what headers does GKE provide.  With AppEngine, `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` is appended to the headers of each request.  However, if the application is deployed to GKE, it looks like `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` is not set.

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Could you clarify if you are looking for `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` in `GKE` or do you want to find something to help you filter those requests?

Comment: @PjoterS my service is deployed in GKE.  Whenever a request comes into the app, I expected to see `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` in the headers but I do not see it.  I expect that to be filled with some sort of ID.

Answer (score 2):

The GCLB definitely sends the `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` to GKE services. I parse that header myself in order to continue the trace which gets started by the load balancer.

Are you using the [Google Cloud L7 load balancer](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/blob/master/README.md)  as your ingress controller or have you set up something else like nginx or Traefik?

Comment: Just for additional confirmation, you can check docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#target-proxies)